# Find the value of id column if checkbox is checked on the basis of column name id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to find the value of id column whose  check box is checked in same row on the basis of column name because id column  position is not fixed. It can be first,last or middle in the table. I have applied the following code:

```
<table id="rowclick2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Des</th>
        <th>ID</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
        </td>
        <td>col 2, row 1</td>
        <td>col 3, row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car"> </td>
        <td>col 2, row 2</td>
        <td>col 3, row 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My jquery is:

```
$("input[name='vehicle']").click(function() {
    alert("djb");

    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("dj");

        if ($(this).closest('table').next('tr').find('th:contains(Jan 3)') == 'true') {
            alert("bhh");
        } else {
            alert("cbjhj");
        }
    }
});
```

Please help to find the  id value whose checkbox is checked. I am new to jquery, javascript.

Comment: What error are you getting right now? Also, can you switch column places, and that's why the ID column is never in the same place?

Comment: change ur alert for "bhh" and "cbjhj" to  alert($(this).val());, if checkbox is click, the alert will show the value, is that the thing u want?

Comment: So how do you know that column is an ID column. Does it always have the same title `ID`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following approach:

```
// binding a change event-handler to <input type="checkbox" /> elements:
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  // assuming you want this to run only when the checkbox is checked:
  if (this.checked) {
    // find the <th> elements:
    var ID = $('th').filter(function() {
        // find those <th> elements whose trimmed-text is exactly 'ID':
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'ID';
      // get the cellIndex property of that element (or the first matched element):
      }).prop('cellIndex'),
      // find the closest <tr> element from the checked <input />:
      IDVal = $(this).closest('tr')
      // find the descendant <td> elements:
      .find('td')
      // find the <td> with the same cellIndex as the <th>
      .eq(ID)
      // retrieve the text:
      .text();
    console.log(IDVal);
  }
});
```

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var ID = $('th').filter(function() {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === 'ID';
      }).prop('cellIndex'),
      IDVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(ID).text();
    console.log(IDVal);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rowclick2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Des</th>
    <th>ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
    </td>
    <td>col 2, row 1</td>
    <td>col 3, row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">
    </td>
    <td>col 2, row 2</td>
    <td>col 3, row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If, however, you use a class-name to identify which cells contains the 'id' associated value, such as `<td class="id"></td>`, this all becomes much simpler:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    // find the closest <tr> element from the :checked <input />:
    var idValue = $(this).closest('tr')
      // find the element with the class of 'id':
      .find('.id')
      // retrieve the text of that element:
      .text();
    console.log(idValue);
  }
});
```

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    var idValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.id').text();
    console.log(idValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="rowclick2" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Select</th>
    <th>Des</th>
    <th class="id">ID</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">
    </td>
    <td>col 2, row 1</td>
    <td class="id">col 3, row 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car">
    </td>
    <td>col 2, row 2</td>
    <td class="id">col 3, row 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`cellIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement).
- jQuery:

  - [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`jQuery.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Please see demo.

based on what I understand from this, *Please help to find the id* **value whose checkbox is checked**.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":checkbox").click(function(){
        alert( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silkherb/tx2asmg6/2/

Answer (score 0):

Add IDs to the checkboxes `id="first"` and `id="second"` to grab the elements:

```
    <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="first"></td>
    <td>col 2, row 1</td>
    <td>col 3, row 1</td>
</tr>`enter code here`
<tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="second"> </td>
    <td>col 2, row 2</td>
    <td>col 3, row 2</td>
</tr>
```

Afterwards, you can use a simple javascript. `.checked` checks whether the checkbox is marked.

```
if(document.getElementById("first").checked == true){
  console.log("do something here 1");
}
if(document.getElementById("second").checked == true){
  console.log("do something here 2");
}
```